# Methods to saving system configuration files

Tags: linux, git, dot-files

Normally user-specific config files would be dotfiles in the home-directory. If the user wanted a little more, they could put it in a dotfiles folder and symlink the files or use gnu stow to handle that.

Is there anything like that for config files that are not in the home folder? For example, if I wanted to track /etc/sudoers in a git repo. Is there another way to do that outside of copying that file to my dotfiles directory, tracking it, and copying it when I make changes?